# Visa requirements for Mexico with Mauritian passport

Tags: visas, mexico

My wife holds a Mauritian passport but has an Indefinite Leave To Remain status in her passport. Will she require a visa to travel to Mexico as I can't find a straight answer anywhere on the net?

Answer (score 1):

As listed in the 2nd exemption on the [consulate website](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/es/contenido/108-visas-for-other-countries):

> According to Mexican regulations which came into force in June 2009, Permanent residents in the United Kingdom wishing to travel to Mexico do not require a visa to enter the country as tourists or business visitors for up to 180 days and as visitors in transit for up to 30 days, regardless their nationality.